Basic return behavior of reactive
Despite reading many tutorials, it's still fundamentally unclear to me what is being passed back from a reactive expression/code block, especialy when code blocks inside reactive become longer. I did some basic tests, assuming reactiveConsole(TRUE) is a proper way of testing these things.
Is the following summary accurate?

without an explicit return statement, reactive always returns the value produced by the last statement within its expression, regardless of whether that value was assigned to a local variable (but see "unexpected" behavior in examples below)
use explicit return statement(s) to prevent returning the result of the final statement, for example to avoid returning a debugging print statement at the end of the expression, to build in if/else logic on what to return, etc.

If there are other important variations on or exceptions to this behavior worth mentioning, please do.
library(shiny)
reactiveConsole(TRUE)

#------single line-----
#direct assignment
x = reactive({5})
x() #-> 5

ans = x()
ans #-> 5

#assign value to local variable, return
x = reactive({tmp = 5
return(tmp)})
x() #-> 5

ans = x()
ans #-> 5

#assign value to local variable, don't return
x = reactive({tmp = 5})
x() #-> [no response]

ans = x()
ans #-> 5 [value unexpectedly returns]


#-----multi-line---
#direct assignment: final line is retained
x = reactive({5
  10})
x() #-> 10

ans = x()
ans #-> 10


#return requested local var, tmp
x = reactive({tmp = 5
tmp2 = 10
return(tmp)})
x() #-> 5

ans = x()
ans #-> 5

#return requested local var, tmp2
x = reactive({tmp = 5
tmp2=10
return(tmp2)})
x() #-> 10

ans = x()
ans #-> 10

#without return
x = reactive({tmp = 5
tmp2 = 10})
x() #-> [no response]

ans = x()
ans #-> 10 [value unexpectedly returns]


I don't know reactive(), but the behaviour you saw is exactly the same as a standard function or block of code in braces.  If your function is
f <- function() {
   x <- 5
}

then calling f() doesn't print anything, but it returns the value 5, because the statement x <- 5 returns the value 5 "invisibly".  In R, things returned invisibly don't auto-print, and the value of the last statement executed in the body of the function is the default return value of the function.
The same is true of the code block
{
  x <- 5
}


had no idea that this is default R behavior. whenever I write a (regular) function, I always assumed one should either 1) explicitly return a variable, or 2) assign some value to a variable towards the end of the function to make that the "implicit" return variable. coming from a different language, silently/invisibly returning the result of the final statement is very unexpected...

There's a function called invisible() that makes a value invisible; you'll see lots of functions ending invisible( something ) to return a value without printing.  Assignment is done in low-level code, but x <- 5 is pretty much equivalent to assign("x", 5); invisible(x), so your "implicit" return variable is really doing that.  You can also experiment with withVisible(  something ) to see the visibility flag explicitly.  For some fun, try withVisible(x <- 5) and withVisible( (x <- 5) ).

A reactive is simply a function. That’s why the behaviour is exactly the same as with a standard function. :-). In this light, myReactive returns the function, myReactive() the function’s current value. All as expected.

@user2554330 very helpful context. but given that withVisible(x<-5) is different from withVisible(x=5) it looks like there's a rabbit hole ahead...

@mrroy:  that's a syntax issue.  The = says to bind 5 to the argument x in the call to withVisible(). It is handled very differently from the expression x = 5.Using <- makes an expression containing an assignment.  You'll see the difference if you use a different variable name:  withVisible(y = 5) is an error, because there's no argument named y.  withVisible(y <- 5) is just another assignment expression.

@Limey yes, all makes sense now. just wasn't aware of standard function return behavior, and that this propagates to the expression inside reactive({}). closest related post I can find is this
